# How to enable displaying the global label unsing FormMultiCheckbox in ZF2?

Tags: zend-framework2, label, zend-form, zend-form-element, zend-form2

I'm using [`Zend\Form\Element\MultiCheckbox`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-form/blob/master/src/Element/MultiCheckbox.php) with [`Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormMultiCheckbox`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-form/blob/master/src/View/Helper/FormMultiCheckbox.php):

**`MyFieldset.php`**

```
// namespace ...;
// use ....;
class MyFieldset extends Fieldset
{
    // ...
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        $this->add(
            [
                'type' => 'multi_checkbox',
                'name' => 'mymulticheckbox',
                'options' => [
                    'label' => _('global label'),
                    'label_attributes' => [
                        'class' => 'col-md-3',
                    ],
                    'value_options' => [
                        [
                            'value' => 'foo',
                            'label' => 'FOO',
                        ],
                        [
                            'value' => 'bar',
                            'label' => 'BAR',
                        ],
                        [
                            'value' => 'buz',
                            'label' => 'BUZ',
                        ],
                    ]
                ],
            ]
        );
    }
    // ...
}
```

**`myform.phml`**

```
use Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormMultiCheckbox;
echo $this->formMultiCheckbox($myFieldset->get('mymulticheckbox'), FormMultiCheckbox::LABEL_PREPEND);
```

It works, but the "`global label`" is not displayed. It gets displayed, when I'm using [`Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormElement`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-form/blob/master/src/View/Helper/FormElement.php), but the `FormMultiCheckbox` seems to ignore the "global `label`".

**How to make `FormMultiCheckbox` display the `label` of the checkbox list?**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `formRow()`. For me it works. This does not appear to be managed in `formMultiCheckbox()`. See lines `182-193`, file [`zend-form/src/View/Helper/FormRow.php`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-form/blob/master/src/View/Helper/FormRow.php#L182-193).

```
// Multicheckbox elements have to be handled differently as the HTML standard does not allow nested
// labels. The semantic way is to group them inside a fieldset
if ($type === 'multi_checkbox'
    || $type === 'radio'
    || $element instanceof MonthSelect
    || $element instanceof Captcha
) {
    $markup = sprintf(
        '<fieldset><legend>%s</legend>%s</fieldset>',
        $label,
        $elementString
    );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, as I wrote in my question, I have already tried it with the `FormRow` view helper. Unfortunately it has the disadvantage, that, then the label position cannot be defined as wished (`formRow($field, 'prepend')` doesn't work for `MultiCheckbox`es). At the end I workarounded by doing everything manually: `'<fieldset><legend>' . $this->translate($myFieldSet->get('mymulticheckbox')->getLabel()) . '</legend>' . $this->formMultiCheckbox($myFieldSet->get('mymulticheckbox'), FormMultiCheckbox::LABEL_PREPEND)` It's ugly, but it works.

Comment: Oh yes, no other alternative.